# When creating and attributing a object: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I'm learning C++ and creating a simple class, tstring, defined by:

- n the number of characters in a string;
- ntotal the total number of characters in the tstring;
- p, pointer to a zone which contains the data.

Hence, this class is composed by a static part (n, ntotal and p) and by a dynamic part (the data itself).

I created three constructors :

*one without parameters;
*one copy constructor;
* one constructor which takes a C-string parameter.

I would like to be able to concatenate one tstring object with one C string, using for example the instructions:

```
tstring x("Hello), y;
y = x + " World";
```

To do this, I am overloading the `+` operator as a non-member function.

**However, when executing the following commands, all runs fine :**

```
tstring x, y;
tstring z = x + y;
```

**But when executing the following ones, I get a "pointer being freed was not allocated" error :**

```
tstring x, y;
tstring z;
z =  x + y;
```

I understand a little bit the logic behind that error but can not find a way to solve it.

Any help is welcome, thank you in advance!

---

You can find my implementation of the `+`operator:

```
tstring operator+ (const tstring& myTstring1, const tstring& myTstring2)
{
    tstring result;
    result.n = myTstring1.nutile + myTstring2.n;
    result.ntotal = myTstring1.ntotal + myTstring2.ntotal;
    result.p = new char[result.ntotal];
    for (int k = 0; k < maTstring1.n; ++k) {
        result.p[k] = maTstring1.p[k];
    }
    for (int l = maTstring1.n; l < maTstring2.n; ++l) {
       result.p[l] = maTstring2.p[l];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The constructor without parameter:

```
tstring::tstring(){
    ntotal = 10;
    n = 0;
    p = new char[ntotal];
}
```

And the destructor:

```
tstring::~tstring(){
    delete[] p;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're missing a copy-assignment operator. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Sounds like he's cocking it up by not using something sane like std::vector. He should learn the sane way to do it.

Comment: the `operator+` function seems to have a lot of typoes, make sure you are copy-pasting code instead of typing it out.  It would help to show the whole tstring class.

Comment: @Mike Seymour : What is needed here operator= or copy constructor? or both?

Comment: @VolAnd A copy-assignment operator (`operator=`), as I said. From the "all runs fine" example, it sounds like there's a working copy constructor.

Comment: Thanks. And link "What is The Rule of Three?" is also usefull

Comment: @Puppy: True, but it's also important to learn how copy semantics work, and writing your own dynamic array/string/whatever is a good learning exercise.